# How to use require in node.js

Tags: node.js

```js
+project
|_____+functions
|      |_______+node_modules
|      |_______index.js
|      |_______package.json
|
|_____+node_modules
|
|_____+public
       |
       |____subject.js
```

I want to access the variable inside the subject.js. I contain the mail Id to be sent when the index.js file is triggered. **index.js** file is a firebase cloud function to send a mail.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var sourceFile = require('../subject.js');

var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://usser@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com');
exports.sendMail=functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
 var mailOptions={
  to: 'badhushaphysics@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Test Mail',
  html: 'Testing with Node.js'
 }
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,response){
  if(err)
  {
   res.send('Mail not sent');
   console.log(err);
  }
  else{
   res.send('Mail sent');
  }
 });
});
```

How to require the variable from the subject.js, to the usage of index.js

Comment: I guess your path is incorrect. try this `var sourceFile = require('../public/subject.js');`

Comment: @distalx **Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '../public/subject.js'** It is said this error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js` file.

**Try**

```
const sourceFile = require('../public/subject.js');
```

**instead of :**

```
var sourceFile = require('../subject.js');
```

*Hope this helps*.

Comment: **Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '../public/subject.js'** It is said this error.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the correct path to `subject.js`?
Well, also try `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));` in your main file that is served. This might work.